# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un loop con dplyr?

Tags: r, bucles, r-dplyr

Estoy modificando varias columnas, a la vez que cambio el argumento de una función. Escribiendo un loop es bastante sencillo, pero quisiera saber cómo puedo hacerlo con dplyr. Este es el código que tengo.

```
for (i in 3:dim(df)[2]) {
  df[[i]] <- paste0(df[[i]], "clase", i - 2)
}
```

Comment: Has formulado otra pregunta casi idéntica pero en inglés, te recomiendo que elimines una de ellas y la que desees conservar esté en castellano.

Answer (score 1):

Este es uno de esos pocos casos en los que con R base logras ser más conciso y claro que con `dplyr`. La idea sería algo así:

```
df[, -c(1,2)] %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(row = as_tibble_row(paste0(., 'clase', 1:length(.)), .name_repair="unique")) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(row)) %>% 
  setNames(names(df[, -c(1,2)]))
```

- Con `df[, -c(1,2)]` seleccionamos todo menos las dos primeras columna
- `rowwise()` es un agrupamiento  por fila
- con `do(row = as_tibble_row(paste0(., 'clase', 1:length(.)), .name_repair="unique"))` generamos para cada fila, un `tibble` con cada columna más la cadena `clase` más un índice por número de columna
- Con  `unnest(cols = c(row))` transformamos cada `tibble` en una fila real
- Por último, configuramos los nombres finales de las columnas.

Comment: muchas gracias, Patricio ¿Pero cómo puedo agregar el iterador dentro del paste0? paste0(df[[i]], "clase", i - 2)

Comment: Es cierto, no vi el índice adicional que querías agregar. Dejamelo pensar.

Comment: @KlausLehmann, ahí te paso una posible solución